# a href"#" is not working with :focus on firefox browser

Tags: html, css

I have this menu that I customized to use it like a select. It work just fine on ie, chrome but on firefox is not working. Normal behavior is: when menu is expanded on focus the links are displayed (help and logoff) and if you click on them will be redirected in other page in the same browser. Wrong behavior on firefox: menu si expanded on focus but links (hep and logoff) are not redirecting.

```
    <ul id="main">
                <li class="username" tabindex="1" >  <a>USER</a>
                    <ul class="curent_buser">
                        <li class="ai"><a class="jaximus"href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki">Help</a></li>
<li class="aj"><a class="jaximus" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki" name="logoff">Log Off</a></li>                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Why is doing this firefox??? I have last version of ff :|

here is a fiddle example: **http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1152/**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the instant you press down on either "Help" or "Log Off" the encompasing a element gets the focus and is active, which "deactivates" this rule:

```
#main li:focus ul, #main a:active + ul{
display:block;
}
```

Thus the link (or more specifically the ul encompassing the link) vanishes before the click on the link has been completed.

At least this seems to be how firefox handles it.

**EDIT:** It should work with adding the selector

```
#main li.username:active ul
```

to above rule.

Comment: yes I know :) but how can I fix that and why only on firefox has this behavior.

Comment: well do you want it to be only displayed when clicked on? if hovering is ok too, just add this to above rule: "#main li.username:hover ul"

Comment: I'd try to modify the CSS rule to match any focused element under `#main li`. This way the elements would be visible and the links would be clickable.

Comment: Nah i also just thought complicated ;)
The edit in my answer should fix the problem for you :)

Comment: @gatub I dont want to use hover :| I want to expand that menu on click.

Comment: @orique can you put that modifies in a fiddle example ?

Comment: @burebistaruler i know, in the edit section of my answer there is the solution WITHOUT using hover

Answer (score 3):

Change your final rule to this:

```
#main li:focus ul, #main a:active + ul,
#main li ul:hover
{
display:block;
}
```

The `#main li ul:hover` rule means that the submenu will stay open long enough for the click to register.

See [forked JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1152/)

p.s. Cool trick, I've never seen a select box launched like this before.